# responding policy-file-request of flash from c#

Tags: c#, sockets, actionscript, policy, cross-domain-policy

i have developed a server application with c# and a client application with flash action script 3.0. Flash socket asking for a policy file when called from a browser with a message

```
<policy-file-request/>
```

everything is normal so far. My server is waiting for this message and sending to client a policy file string which is like this:

```
public const String POLICY_FILE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
    "<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\n" +
    "<cross-domain-policy>" +
    "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />" +
    "</cross-domain-policy>\u0000";
```

this string is being sent this way:

```
if (message.Contains("policy-file-request"))
            {
                client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Statics.POLICY_FILE));
                return;
            }
```

I'm pretty sure that this was working but i really don't know what happened and started not working. When flash client receives this message from server, connection was succesfull and everything was going how it had to go. But now the flash client waits 20 seconds (timeout of flash socket) and throws security exception

```
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]
```

I'm stuck and can't move forward. I'm listening to port 963, server machine fully qualified name is "mypc.domain.local" which can be accessible across my network. there is also an IIS running on this machine and the flash application is hosted here.

```
http://mypc.domain.local:90/page.html
```

this is the way, i call my flash application and

```
mypc.domain.local:963
```

is the address of server running. i am also working on this machine. i tried calling the page `http://localhost:90/page.html` or `http://127.0.0.1:90/page.html` and also tried the connection to server as localhost:963 or 127.0.0.1:963. same result on every combination.

What is wrong here? what could have been changed causing my working code broke down?

Thanks.

Comment: no, all firewalls are off and connections from swf directly are successful. only connections via web browser are not established because of cross domain.

Comment: since you're using http, i'd try using fiddler to help view the actual contents of the messages

Comment: FWIW, in the off chance this is related: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html

Comment: fiddler is a good idea, i will try and tell you the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more code, but based on what you've shown, it appears that when that request comes in, you respond with the contents of the policy file, which isn't an actual valid HTTP response.  My guess for the 20 second timeout would be that it's still waiting for the HTTP headers.

If possible, try to use the HTTP classes already in the BCL instead of doing http 'manually', but if you have to do the socket stuff yourself, then use something like Fiddler during debugging since it's great for identifying violations of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: you mean, policy file request is waiting a response with http respond?